# How to deal with signed numbers correctly and still use "+"

Tags: vhdl, signed, 16-bit

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity alu_16 is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           gt : out  STD_LOGIC;
           lt : out  STD_LOGIC;
           eq : out  STD_LOGIC;
           result : out  SIGNED(15 downto 0);
           overflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           cout : in  STD_LOGIC);
end alu_16;

architecture Behavioral of alu_16 is
    signal inter_res : SIGNED(16 downto 0);
    signal subtraction : SIGNED(16 downto 0);
    signal addition : SIGNED (16 downto 0);
    signal carry_in : STD_LOGIC;
    signal carry_out : STD_LOGIC;
    signal msb_bit_add : STD_LOGIC;
begin
    gt <= '1' when a > b else '0';
    lt <= '1' when a < b else '0';
    eq <= '1' when a = b else '0';
    subtraction <= signed(a) - signed(b);
    addition <= signed(a) + signed(b);
    with sel select 
    inter_res <= addition when "00",
                  subtraction when "01",
                 signed(a) AND signed(b) when "10",
                 signed(a) OR  signed(b) when others;
    carry_out <= inter_res(16);
    msb_bit_add <= std_logic(a(15) + b(15));
    carry_in <= msb_bit_add XOR inter_res(15);
    overflow <= NOT(carry_in XOR carry_out);
    result <= inter_res(15 downto 0);




end Behavioral;
```

So.. I'm trying to make a 16 bit signed adder without using a ripple carry adder. However, I am getting errors about overloading the + operator at the one bit add for msb_bit_add. Can anyone shed some light on what I should do on that line?

Thanks!

Comment: With numeric_std, the rule for addition or subtraction is the size of the result matches the size of the largest input operand.  Since you want 17 bit result, you will need to extend one of your 16 bit arguments.  See "VHDL Math Tricks of the Trade" at:  http://www.synthworks.com/papers/  it shows how to do the extension for unsigned.

Comment: You also might want to think about your gt and lt expressions.  Using std_logic_vector is going to do a lexicographical (string) comparison - this will not work so well if the operands are signed.  You might want to consider using intermediate signals to convert a and b to signed for internal usage.

Comment: I went ahead and just made the input signals signed.

Comment: Also - I sign extended with "a2 <= resize(signed(a), 17);"

Comment: Perhaps you could either answer your own question or update your code and question?